# What did Apple do to the Python framework?

Tags: python, macos

*[tl;dr? see bottom]*

Python on OS X has always been somewhat of an abomination in that it's split up and spread out all across the system. Some in `/usr`, some in `/Library/Python`, some `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`.

Now, as I understand it, the framework is supposed to contain the Python *distribution*, i.e. the bits and pieces that aren't going to change. An example would be headers, the standard library, the binary images, etc.

So as a developer of a [sort-of-popular Python C extension](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/), I think myself to be pretty good at the OS X ecosystem and how to compile Python extensions on it. It wasn't a month ago that [Apple decided to skip on QA](https://github.com/lericson/pylibmc/issues/35), breaking C extension building across the board.

It's broken in yet a new way though, as Apple seem to have decided to remove the better part of the Python distribution. Take a look at the `include/` directory:

```
$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/include/python2.6 
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    30K Jun 25  2010 pyconfig.h
```

Missing something? The `Python.h` header perhaps? What's more, I had woes with `zc.buildout` because it couldn't find `site.py`... Have a look-see:

```
$ python -c 'print __import__("site").__file__'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site.pyc

$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site.py*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    20K May 17 15:40 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site.pyc
```

Missing something? The `site.py` original perhaps?

All in all, it seems Apple are stripping out *vital* developer resources. I confirmed both of these findings on other MacBooks with OS X 10.6.7.

**tl;dr** Apple have removed lots of vital headers and source-code from the Python framework. Has this happened anybody else? If so, when did this happen? Why did it happen? And most importantly, how do I get them back?

Comment: You are usually better of to install a separate version of Python anyway (especially if you want to use numpy/scipy).

Comment: Both look ok for me on my MacBook Pro and my MacPro both with 10.6.7

Comment: But I know this used to work before! And it still does for @Asgeir

Comment: I guess I should've thought of **reinstall Xcode!**

Comment: I know this is old post but OS X Mavericks 10.9+ FYI `Python.framework` "SDK `Python.framework` is deprecated, and the standard `*nix` method of using the `python.h` header should be used instead." https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758680/1896134

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python.h and other headers are included with Xcode. On my system, it's located in both `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h` and `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h`. The latter appears to be installed by the Xcode installer.

Comment: So you still have one in `/System/Library/Python.framework` then. That's my problem, it seems. :-( Nobody knows why either?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it doesn't look like you understand the OS X ecosystem at all. `/System/Library` is for Apple-shipped components of the OS X "distribution"; third parties must not put files in there, but should use `/Library` instead. That's why the built-in Pythons (multiple versions) are in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`, but place the `site-packages` directories in `/Library/Python`, so that third-party modules can be installed there. As for `/usr/bin`, it contains symlinks to the python executable by version, and programs that autoselect the version based on some parameters (see `man python`). It's actually quite logical and tidy.

Now to answer your questions. C headers and other developer resources are not included in the default install of OS X. This is not specific to Python, and was done to save space on a default install. To get the developer resources, you need to install the developer tools. What were you going to do with a C header without a C compiler, anyway?

Comment: The tone of this answer is very poor; you seem to be looking for an argument. I said exactly what you said in your answer, you're reiterating the same information. Very unhelpful.

Comment: What a strange complaint. I answered all of your questions: "Has this happened anybody else? Why did it happen? And most importantly, how do I get them back?" (actually, sorry, I missed "If so, when did this happen?": I think with 10.6). I also answered a question you did not ask directly, but still needed to know (the rationale for the organization of Python files on OS X). I guess the rhetorical question at the end sounds a bit snarky, but given the language in your question ("an abomination", "missing something?", "have a look-see", etc.), I never expected you would be bothered by it.

Comment: Sticking it to the man, as we call it, is a common way to express frustration in dealing with technical difficulties. A lot of people do it; that doesn't mean it's a good idea to reply in a similarly accusing way -- I'm a person, Apple is a company. One of us has a brain. I'm sorry to say that I can't really see how you mean you answered all of those questions; "how do I get them back" is perhaps the top priority question here! **It could be possible that reinstalling Xcode will bring these back, but it's almost a completely fresh install.**

Comment: I'm of the "don't dish it out if you can't take it" school. Did you do a full install of Xcode? The headers are contained in the "UNIX Development" package. Try doing a custom install and selecting just that.

Comment: I don't know how, but somehow the Xcode installer must've skipped installing these headers (and the source-code for the Python standard library..?) even though I'm pretty confident I just told it to do whatever it wanted to by default. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar problems in the past. Space_C0wb0y's suggestion works for me, and using `python_select` I can switch between "default" versions of python. This also de-couples me from XCode. I've installed versions of 2.6 and 2.7 using MacPorts, which by default places the distribution in locations such as `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`. It is the only way I have managed to have consistent installations, including 3rd party modules.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I'd like to have other versions of Python just because Apple decided to break something. This has worked before, of this I am very, very sure. I really want to know what has happened to a system that *used* to work.

Comment: I agree completely, but it is nice to be decoupled from whatever apple decide to do in this respect. I also routinely need to develop and test on 2.6 and 2.7, so the ability to easily switch is good.

Comment: I do my testing on a VMware image of Gentoo Linux, so as to not taint the Apple-provided system substrate.